# Checking a date is between specific dates calculated from today in a particular timezone

Tags: c#, datetime

## Scenario

I have a legacy system where dates are stored in the database in `datetime` fields in `AEST` time (AUS Eastern Standard Time).

I need to retrieve a date form the database and check whether it's between 4pm yesterday and 3.3pm today in `AEST` time.

I'm unsure of the server timezone so I'm converting `UtcNow` to the  `AEST` timezone to get `Today` in `AEST` time and then doing interval calculations to get the specific dates to compare against.

Is the implementation below correct, my current concerns are:

1. Doing the interval calculations to get the specific dates. Is there a better way?
2. Does this account for daylight savings

## Implementation

```cs
DateTime dateFromDbInAEST = // date retrieved from the database (stored in AEST)

TimeZoneInfo aestTimeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");
DateTime todayAEST = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, aestTimeZoneInfo).Date;

DateTime fourPMYesterdayAEST = todayAEST.AddHours(-8).Dump();
DateTime threeThirtyPMTodayAEST = todayAEST.AddHours(15.5).Dump();

bool isBetween = (fourPMYesterdayAEST <= dateFromDbInAEST) && (dateFromDbInAEST <= threeThirtyPMTodayAEST);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first make an extension method, as that will allow a more descriptive notation. Also makes things a wee bit simpler — wrap some some unit tests around that and you can have certainty that it behaves the way you think it ought to behave:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions {

  private static readonly AEST = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("AUS Eastern Standard Time");

  public static bool isWithinWindow( this DateTime instant ) {
    DateTime dtNow  = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc( DateTime.UtcNow, AEST ).Date ;

    // 16:00 on the previous day
    DateTime dtFrom = dtNow
                      .AddDays(    -1 )
                      .AddHours(   16 )
                      .AddMinutes(  0 );

    // 15:30 on the current day
    DateTime dtThru = dtNow
                      .AddDays(     0 )
                      .AddHours(   15 )
                      .AddMinutes( 30 );

    bool withinWindow = instant >= dtFrom && instant <= dtThru ;
    return withinWindow ;
  }

}
```

Once you have that, you can say:

```
public void process() {
  // date retrieved from the database (stored in AEST)
  DateTime dbDateTimeInAEST = getSomeDateTimeValueFromDatabase() ;

  bool isWithinWindow = dbDateTimeInAEST.isWithinWindow()  ;
  if ( isWithinWindow ) {
      // do the processing for things that are within the window
  }
  else {
      // do the processing for things that are outside the window
  }
}
```

And, yes, `TimeZoneInfo` should magically take care of cutovers between daylight savings and standard times.